# PHP no recibe datos de input

Tags: php, javascript, html, entrada, submit

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, al hacer submit no inserta en la base de datos, es mas, solo toma los valores de la ultima fila de la tabla, no se como ponerlo para que recoja bien los valores.

Tambien el input para cantidad siempre obtiene el valor 0 o sin valor.

```
<?php
  //foreach($_POST as $result) {
  //  echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $result . "' );</script>";
  //}
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
  {
   echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: ".$key." - ".$val."' );</script>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])){
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug post_ submit?: " . $_POST['submit'] . "' );</script>";

    $idCliente = $_POST['id_c'];
    $id_producto = $_POST['id_p'];
    $idCantidad = $_POST['sale_price'];
    $Total     = $_POST['cantidad_p'];

    $s_date    = make_date();

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO lending(";
    $sql .= " id_producto,id_cliente,cantidad,total_prestado";
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'{$id_producto}','{$idCliente}','{$idCantidad}','{$Total}*{$idCantidad}'";
    $sql .= ")";

          if($db->query($sql)){
            //update_product_qty($s_qty,$p_id);
            $session->msg('s',"prestamo realizado ");
            redirect('client.php', false);
          } else {
            $session->msg('d','Lo siento, registro falló.');
            redirect('client.php', false);
          }
  }
  else{
    $e_cliente = find_client_by_id((int)$_GET['id']);
  }

?>
<?php

  //if(!$e_cliente){
    //$session->msg("d","Missing user id.");
    //redirect('client.php');
  //}
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
  global $db;
  $filter_Result = $db->query($query);
  return $filter_Result;
}

?>
<?php include_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div >
          <label for="name" class="control-label">Nombres</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($e_cliente['name'])); ?>" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
    <div >
          <label for="lastname" class="control-label">Apellidos</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($e_cliente['lastname'])); ?>" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
    <div >
          <label for="Ci" class="control-label">Ci</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" name="ci" value="<?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($e_cliente['ci'])); ?>" readonly="readonly">
    </div>

</div>
  <p>
  </p>
<div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php echo display_msg($msg); ?>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label class="control-label">Busqueda</label>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Buscar por nombres.." title="Type in a name">
      </div >

    <form id = "tabla_" name="tabla_" method="POST" action="add_sale_lending.php?id=<?php echo $e_cliente['id'];?>" >

      <div >
        <label class="control-label">Cliente</label>
        <input id='submit'  name="id_c" value="<?php echo $e_cliente['id'];?>" >
      </div >
      <div >
      </div >
              <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr class="header">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">#</th>
                          <th>Nombre</th>
                          <th>Disponible</th>
                          <th>Precio</th>
                          <th>Cantidad</th>
                          <th>Opciones</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody  id="product_info"> </tbody>


            <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                      <tr>
                          <td><input id='submit' name="id_p" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
                          <td name = "name_p"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                          <td><input  id='submit'  name="quantity_p" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
                          <td><input  id='submit' name="sale_price" value="<?php echo $row['sale_price'];?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
                          <td><input  id='submit' name="cantidad_p" ></td>
                          <td class="text-center">
                             <div class="btn-group">

                                <button type="submit" name="add_sale_lending" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">Prestar</button>

                                </div>
                           </td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php endwhile;?>
                  <script>
                          let form = document.forms.tabla_;

                          function myFunction() {
                            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
                            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                              if (td) {
                                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                  tr[i].style.display = "";
                                } else {
                                  tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                }
                              }       
                            }
                          };
                  </script>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Solo me dan estos resultados, que no bueno son de la ultima fila

Debug Objects: Hola mundo
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: id_c - 2
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: id_p - 2
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: quantity_p - 7
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: sale_price - 90.00
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: cantidad_p - 4545
add_sale_lending.php?id=2:2 Debug Objects: add_sale_lending - SUBMIT

Comment: Creo que el error viene de tu botón, estás declarando `if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))` cuando debería de ser el atributo **name** de tu etiqueta `button` así; `if(isset($_POST['add_sale_lending']))`

Comment: Gracias Vick, es cierto, ya inserta normal, pero sigue obteniendo los valores de la ultima fila, cuando doy en el boton < value="SUBMIT" - Prestar >

Comment: En la ultima fila te refieres a los inputs donde estás colocando php en sus `Value`?

Comment: <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
en esta parte, al dar click en 
<button type="submit" 
solo pasa en el POST los ultimos valores de toda la tabla

Comment: no pasa el valor del click donde le doy en la fila, supongamos le doy en la 3ra fila, pasa los valores de la ultima, le doy en el boton de la 1ra, sigue pasando los valores de la ultima fila

Comment: para insertar necesitas un bucle que itere tus datos que te llegan desde el formulario

Comment: Hola Reynaldo Por lo que estuve observando, parece que el código fuente que has publicado corresponde a varios archivos, por lo tanto, si es así, ¿podrías replantear tu pregunta colocando el código fuente de cada archivo separado? Es decir, indicando el nombre de archivo y su código fuente correspondiente para poder reproducir tu proyecto.